# Fusion chart issue in IE

Tags: jquery, fusioncharts

Hi
I am using fusion chart free version in my ASP.net application.
It is working fine in Mozilla Firefox... but not shown in IE. am using IE8...

CODE:

```
FusionCharts.RenderChart("/Charts/FCF_MSColumn3D.swf", "", strXML, "Chart1", "550", "400", false, false);
```

this was the error

```
htmlfile: Unknown runtime error
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @mu is too short: I Know, but there is no answer...

Comment: Can you please post the xml and the generated html?